# Displaying Struct information in Coldfusion

Tags: coldfusion

I want to display the value of a struct key like:

```
   #stReviewDetail['tags']['travelParty']['value']#
```

It is possible that `tags`, `travelParty` or `value` is missing. What is the best way to check if the structure hierarchy is available? Something like:

```
<cfif StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail, 'tags') AND 
      StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail['tags'], 'travelParty') AND 
      StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail['tags']['travelParty'], 'value') >
    ....
</cfif>
```

or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: You are on the right track by using StructKeyExists.  However, the real answer depends on what you want to display if some, but not all the keys are present.  If you don't know that, the people on Stackoverflow are the wrong ones to ask.

Comment: This is exactly the approach I'd take too, with the multiple StructKeyExists

Comment: As @DanBracuk said, it depends on what you want.  If you can live with just knowing whether it worked or not, you could just attempt to reference it from within a try-catch block.  If it works, cool, if not, do something sensible in the catch.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Multiple StructKeyExists are ugly, and it's easy to write a function to simplify this:

**Usage:**

```
<cfif CheckNestedKeys(stReviewDetail,['tags','travelParty','value']) >
    #stReviewDetail['tags']['travelParty']['value']#
</cfif>
```

**Code:**

```
<cffunction name="CheckNestedKeys" returntype="Boolean" output=false>
    <cfargument name="Struct" type="Struct" required />
    <cfargument name="Keys"   type="Array"  required />

    <cfset var CurStruct = Arguments.Struct />

    <cfloop index="local.CurKey" array=#Arguments.Keys# >
        <cfif StructKeyExists(CurStruct,CurKey)>
            <cfset CurStruct = CurStruct[CurKey] />
        <cfelse>
            <cfreturn false />
        </cfif>
    </cfloop>

    <cfreturn true />

</cffunction>
```

Comment: Shouldn't this return something different for each test? Perhaps the last key that existed?

Comment: Most times I don't care - it's just a safety check - but it's easy to modify it to return CurKey or an empty string, if that's what you wanted.

Comment: Oh, probably also worth mentioning, in Railo 4.1 I think you'll be able to do:

 `#stReviewDetail['tags']['travelParty']['value'] ?: 'output if not defined'#`

Comment: What benefit does this function serve beyond using structkeyexists On the deepest structure

Comment: compare `CheckNestedKeys(stReviewDetail['tags','travelParty','value'])`

Comment: to `StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail,'tags') AND StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail,'travelParty') AND stReviewDetail(stReviewDetail,'value')`.

Comment: But he's asking about nested structures, not 3 different keys of the same structure.  this example I could understand, but I don't see the point if you're trying to test each container of the deepest structure.  <cfset first.second.third.fourth = "Number 5... alive!"> implicitly creates first["second"] and first["second"]["third"] so there is no point in testing for them.

Comment: I mistyped my example in the comments: `StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail,'tags') AND StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail.tags,'travelParty') AND stReviewDetail(stReviewDetail.tags.travelParty,'value')` - just demonstrates further how its less readable. The code in the answer works for nested structures.

Comment: The automatic creation of structures is irrelevant to testing for existence.

Comment: but why test for them if they're KNOWN to exist?  If I wanted to know if first.second.third.forth was defined I could do so with a simple `structKeyExists(first["second"]["third"],"fourth")` testing for second, and third is redundant, that's why I asked if it should return something besides false. `StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail,'tags') AND StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail.tags,'travelParty') AND StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail.tags.travelParty,'value')` will return the same value as    `StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail.tags.travelParty,'value')`

Comment: The point is that they're not known to exist - as per the question _"It is possible that tags, travelParty or value is missing"_ - so only doing `StructKeyExists(stReviewDetail.tags.travelParty,'value')` can result in an error - they need to be checked sequentially (or with isDefined).

Comment: how could they never be defined?  'value' can't be nested inside nothing? i.e. if value exists then travelParty MUST be defined and contain a structure, therefore, tags must be defined and contain a structure, etc.

Comment: Nobody said they never exist. Maybe sometimes the key is `travelParty` and other times the key is `officeParty` and yet other times there are no `tags` at all.

Comment: I knew I was going to end up with egg on my face, Peter being wrong doesn't happen much... I see my error now, `<cfset first.second.third = "test"> <cfif structKeyExists(first.second.third.fourth,'fifth')>` generates an error `second.third.fourth is undefined in first` which I did not test and though I know why it happened, I assumed structKeyExists would handle being that it didn't exist so I bow to your superiority! But I learned something about structKeyExists and how it is more strict than isdefined in this manner as well.

Comment: It happens way more than you might think. :)

Comment: Peter - I love your humility... and your patience. I didn't understand either until one of your comments towards the end of this thread.

Comment: I have been using this logic for years but now in 2022, I got the first bump when used it with <cfelseif>. The function works fine when called in <cfif> but after years I had to use it in <cfelseif> like <cfelseif CheckNestedKeys(stReviewDetail,['tags','travelParty','value']) > ColdFusion 10 returned error "Variable ___IMPLICITARRYSTRUCTVAR3 is undefined".
After struggling a lot on CF10 I found that it doesn't like it when used an implicit array directly as a parameter to a function (any function) (in <cfelseif>). So I tried the same code on Lucee and ColdFusion 2021. It works fine.

Answer (score 2):

If you know the specific keys, you could just use `isDefined`:

```
<cfif isDefined("stReviewDetail.tags.travelParty.value")>
    <cfdump var="#stReviewDetail.tags#">    
</cfif>
```

Comment: isDefined is logically equivalent to StructKeyExists, but slower.

Comment: kinda... It would give you the answer but it is less accurate.  If you have variables.someVar and use isDefined("someVar") thinking you're looking for form.someVar you'll get true. structKeyExists is more accurate because you must define your structure/scope.  As far as speed, the last test I saw was negligible, but only slower in a false condition.

Comment: This should also be `isDefined("stReviewDetail.tags.travelParty.value")`  I tried to edit it but the changes were rejected.

Comment: IsDefined will potentially return incorrect values when used within a loop over struct/keys.